# Can I transfer my account from Google to Stackexchange?

Tags: support, user-accounts, login

I'm using my Google account to log in to tex.stackexchange. But, you know, what if Google some day deletes my account? And does Google really have be informed each time I log in?

So can I transfer my precious account "Keks Dose" to  a Stack Exchange account without losing my reputation?

Comment: +1 for mistrusting Google. You might want to consider getting a [MyOpenID](https://www.myopenid.com/) account, they seem more trustworthy. (Finally, if you want to remember the number of O's in _to lose_, [the Oatmeal](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/misspelling) is your friend :)

Comment: @doncherry Got MyOpenId, thanks for the hint. And regarding »to lose«, I've to admit, I wrote that obviously wrong since school. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On my user page I see a field "my logins":

[image: mylogins]

When I click on it I can "add more logins ...", that brings me to https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/login?noauto=true&returlUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent where I can add a StackExchange account.